# Using keys inside a secure enclave on a non trusted hardware and OS

Tags: trusted-computing, intel-sgx

Are secure enclaves like intel SGX protected from memory leaks? What if a non trusted privileged user dumps all the physical RAM memory. Is it possible to extract the keys in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full memory dump from a trusted user or a hardware attacker will not reveal the contents of the enclave. The enclave memory is encrypted using a key that is stored only in the CPU, generated at boot, and not present in memory. However, it's important to realize that there are many side-channel attacks coming up which allow a local attacker (a malicious user, privileged or otherwise) to leak sensitive information from the enclave, especially when using modern microarchitectural attacks.